# "Moduli space" of isotropic convex bodies?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, moduli-spaces, convex-geometry, convex-analysis

A lot of questions in convex geometry revolve around the geometry of isotropic convex bodies in $\mathbb{R^n}$.

To my knowledge there is no, or very little study of a space such as :

$$C_n = \{Isotropic \ convex  \ bodies \ of \ \mathbb{R^n} \}/\mathbf{O_n}(\mathbb{R})  $$

That is to say, isotropic convex bodies modulo rotations. (which should be the same as conves bodies quotiented by something like $GL_n(\mathbb{R}) \ltimes \mathbb{R}^n$)

Is there any reference about this ? Can we topologize $C_n$ in a "good way", does it carry any structure ?

Comment: The Banach-Mazur compactum comes to mind. It's not exactly what you're asking for, but is at least closely related.

Comment: Macbeath 1951 "A compactness theorem for affine equivalence-classes of convex regions" might be a reference in the direction you're looking for.